# Sorting on a tokenized field that is not a SortableTextField is not supported in cloud mode

Tags: java, solr

I query data from Solr-8.3.1 but i got error "Sorting on a tokenized field that is not a SortableTextField is not supported in cloud mode." I don't know why.
Below is my query in web and java code.

`select?fq=calling_number:8562099976999&q=*:*&wt=json&group=true&group.field=calling_number`

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("calling_number:(").append(isdn).append(" OR ").append(countryCode + isdn).append(")");
StringBuilder filterString = new StringBuilder("start_time:[").append(startDate).append(" TO ").append(endDate).append("]");

final Map<String, String> queryParamMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
queryParamMap.put("q", queryString.toString());
queryParamMap.put("fq", filterString.toString());
queryParamMap.put("group","true");
queryParamMap.put("group.field", "calling_number");
MapSolrParams queryParams = new MapSolrParams(queryParamMap);
```

Comment: If you want to achieve sort...it should work with fields with string as fieldType...You can have 2 fields here...one with text type which will be tokenized...and other would of string type which you can use for sorting the data...

Comment: ohh. i got it. field calling_number is a array -_-